# Make middle of Word sentence BOLD only

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, ms-access-2010, word-2010

I have an Access 2010 database from within which I need to create letters (Word docs). Certain parts of the letter I would like in bold, but when I try to set it then it also makes the preceding text on the same line bold as well.
I don't think Find would work in this situation (I've found plenty of examples of formatting using Find!), as the data changes; might be possible, but very fiddly determining where it starts and ends.
I can, however, capture the data in distinct blocks as I process it so I have tried something like this...

`With oParagraph
     .Range.Text = sContent
     .Range.InsertAfter (sPreviewLetter)
     .Range.InsertAfter (sECText1)
     .Range.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
End With
With oParagraph
     .Range.InsertAfter (sECText2)
     .Range.Bold = True
End With
With oParagraph
     .Range.InsertAfter (sECText3)
End With`

Nothing seems to be working correctly for me but I'm hoping it is quite simple in reality. In the snippet above, I'd like sECText2 to be bold, but not sECText1 or sECText3.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: OK, maybe a bit of a bodge or just better programming, I'm afraid I don't really know but this gave me what I needed...

oParagraph.Range.Select
            Selection.TypeText (sContent)
            Selection.TypeText (sPreviewLetter)
            Selection.TypeText (sECText1)
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Selection.TypeText (sECText2)
            Selection.Font.Bold = False
            Selection.TypeText (sECText3)

Comment: Will try to remember to add this as an answer once my 8 hours is up!!! I'm sure there's a good reason for the delay.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe a bit of a bodge or just better programming, I'm afraid I don't really know but this gave me what I needed...

`oParagraph.Range.Select
            Selection.TypeText (sContent)
            Selection.TypeText (sPreviewLetter)
            Selection.TypeText (sECText1)
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Selection.TypeText (sECText2)
            Selection.Font.Bold = False
            Selection.TypeText (sECText3)`